# Parsing information from http link to move and reorder files into categories folders

Tags: file, powershell, batch-file, batch-processing, directory

To crawl and rename filenames I using this PowerShell code

```
gci *.pdf | foreach { (iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)") -match 'primary-subject">(.*?)</span>'; $matches[1] }
```

But I need to order and move them into relative *Subject* folders

**This is HTTP** [LINK](https://arxiv.org/list/math/1611).

Text file is so formatted

```
[1] arXiv:1611.00024 [pdf, other]
    Symmetry, Outer Bounds, and Code Constructions: A Computer-Aided Investigation on the Fundamental Limits of Caching
    Chao Tian
    Comments: 34 pages, 7 figures; submitted to IEEE Trans. Information Theory
    Subjects: Information Theory (cs.IT)
[2]  arXiv:1611.00044 [pdf, ps, other]
    Optimal Signaling for Secure Communications over Gaussian MIMO Wiretap Channels
    Sergey Loyka, Charalambos D. Charalambous
    Comments: accepted by IEEE Trans. Info. Theory
    Subjects: Information Theory (cs.IT)
[3]  arXiv:1611.00057 [pdf, ps, other]
    Holomorphy of adjoint L functions for quasisplit A2
    Joseph Hundley
    Comments: 18 pages
    Subjects: Number Theory (math.NT)
[4]  arXiv:1611.00066 [pdf, other]
    Many Haken Heegaard splittings
    Alessandro Sisto
    Comments: 12 pages, 3 figures
    Subjects: Geometric Topology (math.GT)
[6]  arXiv:1611.00069 [pdf, other]
    On singular square metrics with vanishing Douglas curvature
    Changtao Yu, Hongmei Zhu
    Comments: 12 pages, 2 figures
    Subjects: Differential Geometry (math.DG); Metric Geometry (math.MG)
[7]  arXiv:1611.00071 [pdf, ps, other]
    Eigenvalues of rotations and braids in spherical fusion categories
    Daniel Barter, Corey Jones, Henry Tucker
    Subjects: Quantum Algebra (math.QA); Representation Theory (math.RT)
```

I need to extract *Subjects* category name from each file text block

```
Subjects: Information Theory (cs.IT)
Subjects: Information Theory (cs.IT)
Subjects: Number Theory (math.NT)
Subjects: Geometric Topology (math.GT)
Subjects: Differential Geometry (math.DG)
Subjects: Quantum Algebra (math.QA)
```

I don't want include *second tag* like

```
Metric Geometry (math.MG)
Representation Theory (math.RT)
```

So finally I should make this folders like this

```
[folder] Information Theory (cs.IT)
[folder] Number Theory (math.NT)
[folder] Geometric Topology (math.GT)
[folder] Differential Geometry (math.DG)
[folder] Quantum Algebra (math.QA)
```

and move finally files *into* relative subject folders like this

```
[folder] Information Theory (cs.IT)
    |
    |__ [file] Symmetry, Outer Bounds, and Code Constructions...
    |__ [file] Optimal Signaling for Secure Communications...

[folder] Number Theory (math.NT)
    |
    |__ [file] Holomorphy of adjoint L functions...
```

Comment: `This is HTTP LINK.` -the barely structured, difficult to process link with only 25 things per page? Matching to saved documents with changed filenames? Not fun. If only you still had the original filenames, you could get the subject out of the abs page with `gci *.pdf | foreach { (iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)") -match 'primary-subject">(.*?)</span>'; $matches[1] }`.

Comment: mmm..your script recognize subject but don't create folders and move  them inside ordering by primary-subject

Comment: What makes you believe the question would improve by re-posting it with this account instead of the account with which it was [posted before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40526234/1630171)?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I I alerted a moderator for your continuous disturbing operations. Assume your responsibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if its your search but my new code

```
Function Clean-InvalidFileNameChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(260, $res.Length))
}

Function Clean-InvalidPathChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(248, $res.Length))
}


$rootpath="c:\temp2"

$rootpathresult="c:\tempresult"

$template=@'
[3]  arXiv:1611.00057 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Holomorphy of adjoint $L$ functions for quasisplit A2} 
Authors: Joseph Hundley 
Comments: 18 pages 
Subjects: {subject:Number Theory (math.NT)} 
[4]  arXiv:1611.00066 [pdf, other] 
Title: {title*:Many Haken Heegaard splittings} 
Authors: Alessandro Sisto 
Comments: 12 pages, 3 figures 
Subjects: {subject:Geometric Topology (math.GT)} 
[5]  arXiv:1611.00067 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Subsumed homoclinic connections and infinitely many coexisting attractors in piecewise-linear maps} 
Authors: David J.W. Simpson, Christopher P. Tuffley 
Subjects: {subject:Dynamical Systems (math.DS)} 
[21]  arXiv:1611.00114 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Faces of highest weight modules and the universal Weyl polyhedron} 
Authors: Gurbir Dhillon, Apoorva Khare 
Comments: We recall preliminaries and results from the companion paper arXiv:1606.09640 
Subjects: {subject:Representation Theory (math.RT)}; Combinatorics (math.CO); Metric Geometry (math.MG)
'@

#extract utils data and clean 
$listbook=gci $rootpath -File -filter *.pdf | foreach { New-Object psobject -Property @{file=$_.fullname; books= ((iwr "https://arxiv.org/abs/$($_.BaseName)").ParsedHtml.body.outerText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template)}} | select file -ExpandProperty books |  select file,  @{N="Subject";E={Clean-InvalidPathChars $_.subject}}, @{N="Title";E={Clean-InvalidFileNameChars $_.title}}  



#build dirs and copy+rename file
$listbook | %{$newpath="$rootpathresult\$($_.subject)"; New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$newpath" -Force;  Copy-Item $_.file "$newpath\$($_.title).pdf" -Force}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Clean-InvalidFileNameChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(260, $res.Length))
}

Function Clean-InvalidPathChars {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String]$Name
  )

  $invalidChars = [IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars() -join ''
  $re = "[{0}]" -f [RegEx]::Escape($invalidChars)
  $res=($Name -replace $re)
  return $res.Substring(0, [math]::Min(248, $res.Length))
}


$res=Invoke-WebRequest "https://arxiv.org/list/math/1611"
$rootpath="c:\temp"

$template=@'
[3]  arXiv:1611.00057 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Holomorphy of adjoint $L$ functions for quasisplit A2} 
Authors: Joseph Hundley 
Comments: 18 pages 
Subjects: {subject:Number Theory (math.NT)} 
[4]  arXiv:1611.00066 [pdf, other] 
Title: {title*:Many Haken Heegaard splittings} 
Authors: Alessandro Sisto 
Comments: 12 pages, 3 figures 
Subjects: {subject:Geometric Topology (math.GT)} 
[5]  arXiv:1611.00067 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Subsumed homoclinic connections and infinitely many coexisting attractors in piecewise-linear maps} 
Authors: David J.W. Simpson, Christopher P. Tuffley 
Subjects: {subject:Dynamical Systems (math.DS)} 
[21]  arXiv:1611.00114 [pdf, ps, other] 
Title: {title*:Faces of highest weight modules and the universal Weyl polyhedron} 
Authors: Gurbir Dhillon, Apoorva Khare 
Comments: We recall preliminaries and results from the companion paper arXiv:1606.09640 
Subjects: {subject:Representation Theory (math.RT)}; Combinatorics (math.CO); Metric Geometry (math.MG)
'@

#get date and cut with format template, group by Subject and clean Title and Subject for transformation to dir and file name
$grousubject=$res.ParsedHtml.body.outerText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | select  @{N="Subject";E={Clean-InvalidPathChars $_.subject}}, @{N="Title";E={Clean-InvalidFileNameChars $_.title}} | group Subject 

#create dir and files
$grousubject | %{$path= "$rootpath\$($_.Name)" ; $_.group.title | %{New-Item -ItemType File -Path "$path\$_" -Force}   }
```

Comment: Please do not grace zero-effort questions with an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why not? Everything does not have to be paying in life? There can be free of charge sometimes without requiring anything but help ... Are you mod here?

Comment: I understand and agree with this in general, but in this case the question is well asked and can be useful to developers who are looking for how to parse a text. What would an example of an applicant's code have changed, I do not understand? Just to discourage posters who do not make any effort?

Comment: @Esperento57 Dear Esperanto, I advice moderator for Ansgar Wiechers,because it is not the first time that disturbs and tries to corrupt request with his arrogance me and maybe other user questions. At this user it has something that bothers you does not concern nor my requests and neither philosophy of the site (that respect). Thank for reply. I really need to have answer for my question to organize my work better and more fasting. I check now your code. Thanks again

Comment: I see that my initial request had an imprecision. I fix this. Please see again my question. I test your code but it return an error `ConvertFrom-String: Term 'ConvertFrom-String'....` not recognized as a cmdlet name, function. See here for detailed http://i.imgur.com/jPUUsh3.png

Comment: I add also *rename code* specifications that I use but problem seems to join with your code because you had missing my new corrections

Comment: if ConvertFrom-String is not recognized, download last version of PowerShell

Comment: my code did all you want, except your loop on pdf file, i think you can code this ;) try it after donwload last PowerShell version

Comment: Please look here to understand what I mean: [LINK HERE](http://nkj.altervista.org/Altro/2powershell%20-%20Parsing%20information%20from%20http%20link%20to%20move%20and%20reorder%20files%20into%20categories%20folders%20-%20Stack%20Overflow.htm)